# Compose navigation lose state after pop screen (initial composition)

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-lifecycle, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am using compose navigation with single activity and no fragments.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MobileComposePlaygroundTheme {
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    val navController = rememberNavController()
                    NavHost(navController, startDestination = "main") {
                        composable("main") { MainScreen(navController) }
                        composable("helloScreen") { HelloScreen() }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MainScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    val count = remember {
        Log.d("TAG", "inner remember, that is, initialized")
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }

    LaunchedEffect("fixedKey") {
        Log.d("TAG", "inner LaunchedEffect, that is, initialized")
    }

    Column {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp))
        Button(
            onClick = {
                count.value++
                Log.d("TAG", "count: ${count.value}")
            },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Increase Count ${count.value}")
        }
        Button(
            onClick = { navController.navigate("helloScreen") },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
        ) {
            Text(text = "Go To HelloScreen")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun HelloScreen() {
    Log.d("TAG", "HelloScreen")
    Text("Hello Screen")
}
```

[image]

> MainScreen -> HelloScreen -> back button -> MainScreen

After pop HelloScreen by back button, MainScreen restart composition from scratch. That is, not recomposition but initial composition. So `remember` and `LaunchedEffect` is recalculated.

I got `rememberSaveable` for maintaining states on this popping upper screen case. However how can I prevent re-execute LaunchedEffect? In addition, docs saying rememberSavable makes value to survive on configuration change but this is not the exact case.

I expected that LowerScreen is just hidden when UpperScreen is pushed, and LowerScreen reveal again when UpperScreen is popped, like old Android's `onPause()`, `onResume()`, etc.
In Compose, is this not recommended?

ps.
Lifecycle of `Composable` is not tied with `ViewModel` but with `Activity`
It needs more care about initialization of `ViewModel`
Why Compose team design like this?
Can you recommend good architecture sample code?

Comment: this is expected behaviour. When screen disappears, it's removed from the view tree and all the resources are freed. You can use a view model - data stored inside will be saved in such case. Or you can save the data in any storage and read when screen appears.

Comment: Thanks for answer about viewModel. Um.. let's change situation a little. Increase viewModel.count on UpperScreen -> pop UpperScreen -> push UpperScreen again -> count is not zero because viewModel is tied with Activity. How can I distinguish initialization point? I want to initialize only when pushed not when upper screen poped

Comment: view model is tied to navigation route. each time you push a new one - a new view model will be created, unless it's saved(during pop)

Comment: Oh.. I tested it again and confirmed you are right. I got it wrong. Thanks!!!